# Definition in coq using keyword `exists`

Tags: coq, exists, definition

I'm trying to define an entity named `isVector` using the following syntax

```
Require Export Setoid.
Require Export Coq.Reals.Reals.
Require Export ArithRing.


Definition Point := Type.

Record MassPoint:Type:= cons{number : R ; point: Point}.

Variable add_MP : MassPoint -> MassPoint -> MassPoint . 

Variable mult_MP : R -> MassPoint -> MassPoint .

Variable orthogonalProjection : Point -> Point -> Point -> Point.

Definition isVector (v:MassPoint):= exists A, B :Point , v= add_MP((−1)A)(1B).
```

And the Coq IDE keeps complaining that there's a syntax error for the definition. Currently, I haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many problems here.

First, you'd write:

```
exists A B : Point, …
```

with no comma between the different variables.

But then, you also have syntax errors on the right-hand side. First, I'm not sure those 1 and -1 operations exist. Second, function calls would be written this way:

```
add_MP A B
```

You can write them the way you do:

```
add_MP(A)(B)
```

But in the long run you should probably become used to the syntax of function calls being just a whitespace! You might need to axiomatize this `-1` operation the way you axiomatized other operations, unless they are a notation that you defined somewhere but did not post here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. 
After experimenting a little bit. Below is the solution that works.

```
Definition Point:= Type.

Record massPoint: Type := cons{number: R; point: Point}.

Variable add_MP: massPoint -> massPoint -> massPoint.
Variable mult_MP: R        -> massPoint -> massPoint.


Definition tp (p:Point) := cons (-1) p.

Definition isVector(v:massPoint):= exists A B : Point, v = add_MP(cons (-1) A)(cons 1 B).
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out!